# JVM not killed on SIGPIPE

Tags: java, jvm, signals, sigpipe

What is the reason for the JVM handling SIGPIPE the way it does?

I would've expected for

```sh
java foo | head -10
```

with

```java
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Stream.iterate(0, n -> n + 1).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

to cause the process to be killed when writing the 11th line, however that is not the case. Instead, it seems that only a `trouble` flag is being set at the PrintStream, which can be checked through `System.out.checkError()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens is that the SIGPIPE exception results in an IOException.

For most `OutputStream` and `Writer` classes, this exception propagates through the "write" method, and has to be handled by the caller.

However, when you are writing to System.out, you are using a `PrintStream`, and that class *by design* takes care of the `IOException` of you.  As the javadoc says:

> A `PrintStream` adds functionality to another output stream, namely the ability to print representations of various data values conveniently. Two other features are provided as well. Unlike other output streams, a `PrintStream` never throws an `IOException`; instead, exceptional situations merely set an internal flag that can be tested via the `checkError` method.

> What is the reason for the JVM handling SIGPIPE the way it does?

The above explains what is happening.  The "why" is ... I guess ... that the designers wanted to make `PrintStream` easy to use for *typical* use cases of `System.out` where the caller doesn't want to deal with a possible `IOException` on every call.

Unfortunately, there is no elegant solution to this:

- You could just call `checkError` ...
- You should be able get hold of the `FileDescriptor.out` object, and wrap it in a new `FileOutputStream` object ... and use that instead of `System.out`.

---

Note that there are no strong guarantees that the Java app will only write 10 lines of output in `java foo | head -1`.  It is quite possible for the app to write-ahead many lines, and to only "see" the pipe closed after `head` has gotten around to reading the first 10 of them.  This applies with `System.out` (and `checkError`) or if you wrap `FileDescriptor`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That reasoning makes sense.. in most use cases it would probably just be annoying to deal with IOExceptions each time something is up with the pipe. The approach using the `FileDescriptor` seems like an elegant way around it if that behaviour is preferred.

Comment: Let me know if it works.  I haven't tried it.  I figured it out by looking at what happens inside the `System` class ... and I may have gotten it wrong.  (I >>think<< that the relevant classes, fields and constructors are all `public`.)

Comment: When you want to write to stdout, you need `FileDescriptor.out`. Generally, `PrintStream` is a horrible faulty design, but unlike the other Java 1.0 mistakes, it has not been deprecated due to the prominent placement in the `System.out` field.

Comment: Seems to be possible, yes. I guess that should then preferably be wrapped in a custom PrintStream which then exits on an IOException.

Comment: @Holger Care to elaborate on that? In what ways do you consider it faulty?

Comment: @leyren `PrintStream` is a subtype of `OutputStream`, mixing up the concepts of a byte stream and a character stream. Similar wrongly designed classes, e.g. `LineNumberInputStream` and `StringBufferInputStream`, have been deprecated. As said, `PrintStream` has not, despite there is a replacement for it, `PrintWriter`, due to the compatibility issues, as `System.out` can’t be changed. But even the replacement shares the horrible behavior of swallowing exceptions and only telling *that* an exception has occurred (a `boolean` value), but not *which* exception (no way to get the original exception